# How to work on downloaded copies of database tables in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, editing, qgis-2, postgis-2.0

I want to provide the online editing facility from postgres database. but it seems if I use Live database it slows down all the function of qgis as its pulls data from online server for every operation such as pan, zoom , open  attributes table etc.

Is it advisable to to make a copy of data(tables) in local machine say a memory layer, edit it and then upload the changes back to server ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

QGIS comes with "offline editing" functionality in core. This downloads the data to a local spatialite database, so you can work on an offline copy and the delay caused by network roundtrips is gone. This is not a memory layer but if I understand correctly, that's just an example and not mandatory.

To enable offline editing, you have to check the offline editing plugin in the plugin manager and then use the Plugins > Offline editing menu to make a local copy and after the session to synchronize it back to the server.

Comment: Thanks Matthias that was good to know we have this great feature inbuilt in QGIS . I will give it a try lets hope it works with my custom plug-in.